# Embedding new fonts to plot in ggplot2, R (mac)

Tags: r, pdf, fonts, ggplot2

I've been trying to export a *ggplot2* plot to PDF. The problem is that I've been adding exotic font to my plots, and -as a consequence- the exported PDF don't show any text.

I made sure to import my font as such:

```
library(extrafont)
font_import(pattern = 'Arch')
loadfonts()
```

and I export to a PDF after my *ggplot2* plot is put in a variable "`p`" :

```
ggsave("myPlot.pdf", plot=p,  width=4, height=6)
embed_fonts("myPlot.pdf", outfile="myPlot_embed.pdf")
```

I then get an error saying:

```
GhostScript was not found
```

This page, however, seems to suggest no other steps should be needed on Mac OS (there's an extra step on Windows): https://github.com/wch/extrafont

Any idea on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This might be a silly question, but have you got GhostScript installed? The linked extrafont ReadMe states that GhostScript is required. The [main GS pages](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) don't have a binary download for Mac OS X, but you could compile from source or get one from elsewhere (e.g. http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/).

Comment: you could try the [showtext package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/showtext/index.html) instead, it uses a completely different approach, and I find it quite promising.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The instruction guidelines for the *extrafont* package you quoted (**https://github.com/wch/extrafont/blob/master/README.md**) clearly state:

> *"You must have Ghostscript installed on your system for embedding fonts into PDF files."*

So as a start, please check if you have Ghostscript installed at all:

1. If yes, make sure it is in the `$PATH`, or that its installation location is included in the `$PATH` variable.
2. If no, install Ghostscript first. You can use the method described below.

---

## 1. Installing MacPorts

First, install the **[MacPorts](http://macports.org/)** framework. MacPorts provides a package management system and ready-made packages which allow you to install a log of GNU and other Free Software packages.

Installation instructions are different, depending on your version of OS X:

- **https://www.macports.org/install.php**

After you have MacPorts, run this command in a Terminal.app window:

```
sudo port selfupdate
```

### 2. Installing Ghostscript

MacPorts has a Ghostscript package. You can install it like this, via commands in a Terminal.app window:

```
sudo port install ghostscript
```

This command will draw in and install more packages which are required by Ghostscript as *"dependencies"*.

**Please note:**

1. After this installation, you'll have a Ghostscript executable placed as `/opt/local/bin/gs`. (There will be even more helper programs in `/opt/local/bin/`.)
2. This requires that you need to put that directory into your `$PATH`. Therefore, put this line into your `~/.bashrc`:

   ```
   export PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH
   ```

---

There are other options which you could try to install Ghostscript. One is **[HomeBrew](http://brew.sh/)** -- but I have no personal experience with this.